# How select an element by xpath and click on it with puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xpath, automation, puppeteer

I tried this simple example to click a link, but it seems that it's not working.
The example is bascily to click a login button in youtube.com
error throw

```
(node:12304) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: youtubeLoginButton.evaluate is not a function
    at C:\Users\GoodBoy\Desktop\code\Puppeteer\scrape-content-from-website\bot.js:17:30
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
(node:12304) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise 
which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:12304) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero 
exit code.
```

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

;(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        defaultViewport: null,
        args: ['--start-maximized'],
    })
    const page = await browser.newPage()

    await page.goto('https://www.youtube.com/')

    const youtubeLoginButtonXpath = '//*[@id="buttons"]/ytd-button-renderer/a'

    const youtubeLoginButton = await page.$x(youtubeLoginButtonXpath)

    await youtubeLoginButton.evaluate((form) => form.click())

    await browser.close()
})()
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work (I've modified a bit your XPath) :

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://www.youtube.com',{ waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
const elements = await page.$x('(//div[@id="buttons"]/ytd-button-renderer/a)[1]')
await elements[0].click() 
await page.screenshot({path: 'full.png', fullPage: true});
await browser.close();
```

Output : screenshot of login page (to upload a new video)

[image: Login]